# Parse: How to know if user has a password?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to find out if user has a password so that I can show/not show a button to change password for example. How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

This is to differentiate users with passwords vs logged in via Facebook. I can know if user is linked to FB. But I don't know if they have a password set.

Comment: define global variable "HasPassword" and save it in (session or cookie ....)  when user logedin check if password  is empty make HasPassword=false else HasPassword=true, then ChangePasswordBtn.Visible=HasPassword

Comment: There is ambiguity in your question...

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.User.html

Comment: @pedram what kind of ambiguity?

Comment: @ShanShan, I have methods to know if user is linked to FB but how do I know if they have a password?

Comment: @SuhailKeyjani, users can login via FB but have a password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know if a Facebook user has a password set or not. You also cannot detect anything on cloud when a user changes his/her password at any time. Given that your app has to provide an interface to the users to set any password in the first place, you can write a customised password set/reset cloud function which not only resets the users password but it also flags the user as password enabled. In your app, you check this user field and determine what to show in your interface.